# Advantage and Disadvantage using Mel Spectrograms over STFT in speech/waveform synthesis

Tags: spectrogram, stft, speech-processing, speech-synthesis

I want to ask you a question about the waveform synthesis or more spesifically speech synthesis. Most of the state-of-the art papers use mel-spectrograms as their inputs, because it mimics the human ear in a best way. However, there is no inverse transformation that maps mel-spectrograms into waveforms without loosing any information(other than Griffin-Lim phase estimation algorithm) because we lost phases when we transfrom our STFT into Mel-spectrogram.
My question is why directly using STFT instead of Mel-spectrograms as input and then train it some network like U-nets, ResBlocks etc, then convert it using iSTFT directly to get the predicted synthesized waveform, then optimize the network weights by GAN-based discriminator losses is not preferred? Does it make sense?  Does it has a clear problem for using it that I can not see now.